# NodeJS Stream Pipeline - The "val" argument must be an instance of Readable, Iterable, or AsyncIterable. Received an instance of WriteStream

Tags: node.js, stream, pipeline

**File: `index3.js`**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

'use strict';

import { pipeline } from 'stream/promises'
import { realpathSync, createReadStream, createWriteStream } from 'fs';
import { pathToFileURL } from 'url';

async function doStuff() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let readStream = createReadStream("input.js");
        let writeStream = createWriteStream("output.js");

        pipeline(
            readStream,
            writeStream,
            async(err) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.error('failed', err);
                    reject({res:'Pipeline failed', err});
                } else {
                    console.log('succeeded');
                    resolve('succeeded');

                }
            }
        );
    });
}

export default function myFunc() {
    doStuff().catch(err => console.log(err));
}

function wasCalledAsScript() {
    const realPath = realpathSync(process.argv[1]);
    const realPathAsUrl = pathToFileURL(realPath).href;
    return import.meta.url === realPathAsUrl;
}

if (wasCalledAsScript()) {
    myFunc();
}
```

**Running with Node v16.15.0**

```
# node index3.js 
node:internal/errors:465
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "val" argument must be an instance of Readable, Iterable, or AsyncIterable. Received an instance of WriteStream
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)
    at makeAsyncIterable (node:internal/streams/pipeline:100:9)
    at pipelineImpl (node:internal/streams/pipeline:263:13)
    at node:stream/promises:28:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at pipeline (node:stream/promises:17:10)
    at file:///var/www/html/index3.js:14:9
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at doStuff (file:///var/www/html/index3.js:10:12)
    at myFunc (file:///var/www/html/index3.js:32:5) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

I've tried every combination of async and await, etc., that I can think of, and I just get this error every time I try to use `createWriteStream`. I eventually want to add a `Transform` in here to modify each *line* before writing, (and I'd love an example of how to do that with `pipeline`, as most tutorials online use `pipe`,) but I can't even get a simple read-then-write to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're doing this:

```
import { pipeline } from 'stream/promises'
```

That gets you the version of `pipeline()` that already returns a promise and does NOT accept a regular callback as the last argument.  But, you're passing it a callback.  Since it doesn't use callbacks, it's expecting that argument to be something else other than a callback and thus you get an error.

You can either switch to this:

```
import { pipeline } from 'stream'
```

So, you're getting the version of pipeline that uses a callback.

Or, since you appears to actually want the promise anyway, don't pass the callback and use the promise that the `pipeline()` from `import { pipeline } from 'stream/promises'` already returns.

```
function doStuff() {
    let readStream = createReadStream("input.js");
    let writeStream = createWriteStream("output.js");

    return pipeline(
        readStream,
        writeStream,
    );
}
```